# how download managers like IDM,orbit ,... disable built-in chrome download manager

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, download-manager

I want when download links clicked in chrome my own custom window showed instead showing built-in chrome download manager window. how? how disable the built-in chrome download manager? I read the entire chrome extension API document but doesn't found anything.

Comment: Something like this [possibly] [upcoming feature](http://lifehacker.com/enable-this-flag-to-view-chrome-downloads-as-card-notif-1721280855)? And anyway why do you think you can't do it via [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) and [notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) or any other means of displaying the info (windows, popups, panels)?

Comment: because I'm writing a download manager and I want when download links clicked my app window showed instead chrome download manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension: How to override download dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006028/chrome-extension-how-to-override-download-dialog)